# Remove lines based on pattern but keeping first n lines that match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to remove lines from a text file based on pattern but I need to keep the first n lines that match the pattern.

Input

```
% 1 
% 2
% 3
% 4
% 5
text1
text2
text3
```

output

```
%1
%2
text1
text2
text3
```

I used `sed /^%/d` file but it deletes all the lines starting with %, `sed 3,/^%/d` doesn't work either. I need to keep first n lines of the pattern and delete the rest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to delete all lines starting with % put preserving the first two lines of input, you could do:

```
sed -e 1,2b -e '/^%/d'
```

Though the same would be more legible with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR <= 2 || !/^%/'
```

Or, if you're after performance:

```
{ head -n 2; grep -v '^%'; } < input-file
```

If you want to preserve the first two lines matching the pattern while they may not be the first ones of the input, `awk` would certainly be a better option:

```
awk '!/^%/ || ++n <= 2'
```

With `sed`, you could use tricks like:

```
sed -e '/^%/!b' -e 'x;/xx/{h;d;}' -e 's/^/x/;x'
```

That is, use the hold space to count the number of occurrences of the patterns matched so far. Not terribly efficient or legible.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane. It worked. Thanks for the additional info as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid `sed` alone is a bit too simple for this (not that it would be impossible, rather complicated - see e.g. [sed sokoban](http://sed.sourceforge.net/local/games/sokoban.sed.html) for what can be done).

How about `awk`?

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { c = 0; }
{
    if (/^%/) {
        if (c++ < 3) {
            print;
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

If you can rely on using recent enough BASH (which supports regular expressions), the awk above can be translated to:

```
#!/bin/bash -
c=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^% ]]; then
        if ((c++ < 3)); then
            printf '%s\n' "$line"
        fi
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done
```

You can also use `sed` or `grep` to do the pattern matching instead of the `=~` operator.

Comment: To match a line starting with % in shell, no need for regexps or ksh/bash specific features like `[[`, you can use `case $line in %*)`. Doing it this way with shells, especially bash, is going to be terribly inefficient. Using loops in shells is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Thanks @peterph. Since my files are huge, I was really looking for something like Stephane's answer. Thanks again

Comment: @Jana No problem, it wasn't just really clear to me, whether the lines matching he pattern were supposed to be only at the beginning of the file or interspersed with the rest. That's why I used the loops.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl [one-liners](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/perl_oneliners.shtml) solution:

```
# in-place editing
perl -i -pe '$.>2 && s/^%.*//s' filename.txt

# print to the standard output
perl -ne '$.>2 && /^%/ || print' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '\n' ';' < input | sed 's/% /##/3g' | tr ';' '\n' | sed '/##/d'
```

I replaced new line characters with ';' to obtain single line string, then turned all but first two occurrences of pattern into ## marking with sed 's/pattern/##/3g' (replace from third to last occurrence of pattern in line), changed back ';' to '\n' and finally removed marked lines.

Comment: Thanks @Nykakin. The pattern replacing for my data won't be efficient. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^%/{
3,$d}' '% 1 
% 2
% 3
% 4
% 5
text1
text2
text3'
```

One way of removing the extra lines.

Edit: my answer works under the same condition as `Stephane Chazelas`'s if the % rows doesn't occur first, it won't work.

---

Nerd sniping.

```
sed -n '/^% [^12]*$/!{
/^% [12][[:digit:]]\{1,\}/n
p}' file.txt
```

Will work regardless of where the `% number` string is found in the stream.
Any line that starts with `%` and ends with any number of characters besides `1` or `2`, which we negate. That address matches anything besides `/% [A-Za-z3-9]*/` leaving an blind spot. Numbers between 10-29 will print still. So we nest a second address to match that range and skip the line.

But awk would still be better.